# Getting coordinates of chart on selecting plot in highcharts

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts, lazy-loading

I am generating one image using High-Charts library but i have 40000 polygon series so it takes lot of time in plotting all those points.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>


  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>




<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {

 var options = {
        chart :{
                  type: 'polygon',
                  renderTo: 'container',
                  zoomType:'x'

        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: false,
            gridLineWidth:0,
            lineWidth:0,
            labels:{
                enabled: false
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: false,
            gridLineWidth:0,
            lineWidth:0,
            labels:{
                enabled: false
            }
        },
         plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor:'black',

            }
        },  
        series: []
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

        options.series=data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    })
    $.getJSON('title.json', function(title) {
        options.title.text=title;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    })

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.base.is/highcharts-downsample.js"></script>
<script src="http://highcharts.base.is/demo_data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>
```

**sample data.json file**

```
[{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61448208.5, 10791], [61453100.5, 20575], [61451242.5, 24291], [61446350.5, 14507]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61453100.5, 20575], [61453544, 21462], [61451686, 25178], [61451242.5, 24291]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61453544, 21462], [61453681.5, 21737], [61451823.5, 25453], [61451686, 25178]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61453681.5, 21737], [61459631.5, 33637], [61457773.5, 37353], [61451823.5, 25453]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61459631.5, 33637], [61462023.5, 38421], [61460165.5, 42137], [61457773.5, 37353]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61462023.5, 38421], [61462226, 38826], [61460368, 42542], [61460165.5, 42137]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61462226, 38826], [61462340, 39054], [61460482, 42770], [61460368, 42542]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61462340, 39054], [61462372.5, 39119], [61460514.5, 42835], [61460482, 42770]] } 
,{"showInLegend": false,"color": "#FFFFFF", "data": [[61462372.5, 39119], [61462429.5, 39233], [61460571.5, 42949], [61460514.5, 42835]] } 

]
```

Is there any way to down sample multiple series to some 100's or create a mouse event on selection of area so that plot can regenerate plot based on coordinates and read chunk of json data within that range.

Comment: See the lazy loading example available on highchart's site.it loads 1.7 million points

Comment: But in my case i have muliple data series instead of mutliple points in data.

Comment: you can try min max on each 100's points.the examples states that on how you get x coordinates for start and end points

Comment: In my case, one series has just one 4 points (for drawing trapezium). http://www.filedropper.com/data_5  Can u pls help me how can i do that with lazy loading.

Comment: In case of multiple polygon series lazy loading might come down to loading different sets of series depending of current zoom. In full zoom out view quantity of series should be reduced and when zooming in new series could be loaded. There is no default function in Highcharts to down sample multiple series.

Answer (score 1):

If your data sets sizes are 50,000 points and beyond, you can consider using [the Highcharts Boost module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module), released in the beginning of 2017 if memory serves. There are some great examples, like this [Highcharts line chart with 600,000 data points across 600 series.](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/samples/highcharts/boost/line-series-heavy/)

You just include the highcharts Boost module, either [directly in a separate  tag](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js), or if using NPM just import the boost module from the highcharts package:

```
import boost from 'highcharts/modules/boost'
```

Then, you can add some boost options in your Highcharts options object, as an example:

```
{
    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Boost'
    },

    series: [{
       boostThreshold: 1, // Boost when there are more than 1                     
                            // point in the chart.
        data: [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]],
    }]
};
```

I've found that module to be of great help as I'm working with multiple series of > 100,000 data points each and multiple charts on one page.